# Kill Java process with a vbscript

Tags: java, process, vbscript, kill

I have some java processes running and I want to end a certain java process.
I have installed jdk so I can use jps.exe [output = PIDNumber Processname] to view the running java tasks. 
The challenge is that I want to kill a certain processname with a vbscript. So I have to run jps.exe via script and put the output into an array.

Any Hints how to achieve the goal are appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: For what reason do you want to kill the process? I dont think its a good idea, but maybe you have a good reason...

Comment: ... I have good reasons, as the process is a java server on a Windows platform I have to stop the server before updating and as I can't kill all java processes, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

`ShellCommandToRun = "jps" 

 Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Set objExec = objShell.Exec(ShellCommandToRun) 

 strPingResults = objExec.StdOut.ReadAll 

 WScript.Echo strPingResults`

Answer (score 0):

you can use [PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx). it can terminate system processes 
you have to need to download the executable and place it in the same directory as the script or add it's path in the `WshShell.Exec` call